# Moving data between columns of a row?

Tags: database-design, rdbms

I am designing a table where in last five changes will be maintained for a field. So the table design is something like this:

```
----------------------------------------------------------
| Name | ValRev1 | ValRev2 | ValRev3 | ValRev4 | ValRev5 | 
----------------------------------------------------------
```

The values will now be rolling over from `ValRev1 -> ValRev2 OR ValRev1 -> ValRev2 -> ValRev3`
as the updates happen.
How to implement this rolling window over columns of data of a single row?

Comment: Having columns with the same name but different numbers at the end is almost always a sign of a de-normalized data model. You should have 5 rows, rather than 5 columns.

Comment: Sorry, did not understand as to how would using rows help in implementing rollover?